# How do I count the number of variations of a golf course?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out the amount of variations I can have for a golf course but getting stuck on how to calculate it.

Basically the problem is this:

I have a course with 18 holes and 3 (blue, white and red) tees. How many scorecard variations can I get but using a different tee on a hole?

So I can use the red tees on all holes is 1 variation. All blue tees is another variation. All white tees is another. 17 white and 1 red is another. 17 red and 1 blue is another. And so on.

Would I do:

18 to the power of 3?
3 to the power of 18?

I figured it would be 3 to the power of 18, but not positive.

Comment: Just trying by hand for two holes would be enlightening.

Comment: Try this simpler question first: what if there are just 2 holes, and still 3 tees? .... Great minds think alike. :-)

Comment: You are correct If each hole is considered independent with the tea choices. Having exactly 1 red tea and 17 blue for example can be done multiple ways

Comment: @RossMillikan good point. I will look at 2 holes to see the combos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, I like to make it a simpler problem to see if the logic holds.

For instance, instead of $18$ holes, let's make it $2$ holes. So, we could have possibilities $\{bb,br,bw,rb,rr,rw,wb,wr,ww\}$, which is nine possibilities, or $3^2$.

That makes sense, there are three independent choices for each hole, so we have $3\cdot3$ possibilities in total. And we would have $3^{18}$ choices for eighteen holes.

The general study of counting things like this can be found in an introductory combinatorics class. You can also look for high-school level books on discrete mathematics, they might have these topics. One text I enjoyed in high school, in particular, is called "For All Practical Purposes".

Comment: Thanks. Like you and @Ross said I started with 2 holes and got this same conclusion. Sometimes I jump right into the main problem without thinking smaller first.